# A Nameless Spectre

Tags: riddle

> Come gather round, a story I have to tell
>     It should be familiar, you ought know well
>     Of things past, I give life anew
>     Of things to come, I know not false from true
>     Who am I you say, I ask you the same
>     Speak my name right, the answer you shall claim

**Hint 1:**

> While some call them unoriginal, many would be lost without my tales.

Comment: "ought know" or "ought to know"?

Comment: I intentionally omitted the "to" for flavor thinking it would still be acceptable (grammatically). The change would not affect the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bouncing off the earlier comments, are you an

> echo

This spectre is

> quite familiar and repeats past (not future) sounds anew. The last two lines refer to the echo repeating what you say, even the word echo itself.

Hint:

> Bats, dolphins and whales use echoes for navigation.

Comment: "Bouncing off the earlier comments.." <- love what you did here. Great job!

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> MEMORY?

*Come gather round, a story I have to tell*

> Memories tell a story.

*It should be familiar, you ought know well*

> When we retain memories of something, it's familiar to us.

*Of things past, I give life anew*

> Reliving the past ...

*Of things to come, I know not false from true*

> ... but no knowledge of the future.

*Who am I you say, I ask you the same*
*Speak my name right, the answer you shall claim*

> I think I remember this answer ...

Comment: Wow! However, I feel the intended answer better fits the puzzle, particularly the last two lines of the riddle.

Answer (score 3):

Are you:

> **HISTORY**?

*Come gather round, a story I have to tell.*
*It should be familiar, you ought know well*

> History - which *has* (i.e. contains) the word 'story' within it - is something you study in school, hence it is familiar and something everybody who has ever been to school should be aware of.

*Of things past, I give life anew*

> History concerns things that have already happened - it is the study of the past. Talking of history can metaphorically make you feel like you are bringing events from long ago back to life.

*Of things to come, I know not false from true*

> It is not - and cannot be - the study of the future; it knows nothing about things that have not happned yet...

*Who am I you say, I ask you the same*

> If you want to know who someone from the past was, you can generally find out as the things they did, where they lived, etc. are all preserved by history - books, encyclopedias, census records, birth/death/marriage registers, the Internet... History asks 'who was this person?' and also knows the answer!

*Speak my name right, the answer you shall claim*

> The word 'history' sounds like *'his story'*, which is precisely what the narrator is telling us!

As for the title:

> 'The spectre of history' is a common phrase, often used with 'looms large' when somebody has a lot to live up to because of their predecessors' past achievements or when things that happened in the past continue to haunt them and appear to prevent them achieving something... (Think every Manchester United manager after Alex Ferguson!)

Comment: Oh my, another wonderful take. I guess I made the riddle too vague? :D Same with Rand al'THor's answer though, the intended solution better matches the last two lines.

Answer (score 3):

Is it:

> Folklore

Come gather round, a story I have to tell

> It's literally a story to tell

It should be familiar, you ought know well

> Well it's a traditional stories, you ought to know some

Of things past, I give life anew
Of things to come, I know not false from true

> It's about things of the past, but been retold over time true or not

Who am I you say, I ask you the same

> It varies depending on your understanding

Speak my name right, the answer you shall claim

> Not sure if this is a hint or not, but well Folklore is a combination of 2 specific words

*Update hint 1:*

> Some can say many folklore tales have so many variation that lost it originality. It can be use to pass beliefs so people don't lost.

Comment: Nope. I'll add a hint before the day ends in my hemisphere so do try again.

Comment: @greysaff okay, hint 1 did nothing for me, I can rationalized and say my answer fit. I think it's still too vague

Comment: Well, aren't riddles supposed to be vague? And don't think too literally about the stories :D Seriously though, while the current answers do somehow fit, it's in the last two lines where the intended answer has an advantage.

Comment: Hmm I see, I just really hope that hint 1 can give me a new perspective. Thanks for clarifying some point